the n-th transvectant of two homogenous polynomials
In Chapter 2 of the book "Beyond the Quartic Equation," there is a brief section that discusses the transvectants of two homogeneous polynomials. The book defines the n-th transvectant of two homogeneous polynomials using the following formula:
$$(f,g)^n:=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{\partial^nf(x,y)}{{\partial x}^{n-k} \partial y ^k}\right) \left(\frac{\partial^n g(x,y)}{{\partial x}^k {\partial y}^{n-k}}\right) $$
and states that:

The second transvectants $(f,g)^2$ are also known as Hessians and can also be expressed by the determinant
$$(f,g)^2=\left|\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x ^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}\\
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y \partial x}& \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}
\end{matrix}\right|$$

but from the previous formula in this book, we have
$$(f,g)^2=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x ^2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y ^2}-2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial y}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y ^2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x ^2}  $$
and it is completely different from the determinant formula.
First question: Is it just a mistake in this book or is there a reason for it?
Second question: What are the applications of transvectants in mathematics? I search about this concept but there are few sources about this. Only a few lines have been written about this in the mentioned book:

The special symmetry of the regular polyhedra corresponds to the vanishing of some special functions of these polyhedral polynomials known as transvectants.

so what is the exact correspondence between regular polyhedra and the vanishing of transvectants?

Not a direct answer, but you might be interested by some publications of J. Olver which are often clear, for example this one about differential invariants.

It is only when $f=g$ that the second transvectant is called the Hessian. In that case the two formulas differ by a factor of $2$.
Note that the first formula is not the best normalization for transvectants, and I think it is better to use the notation $(f,g)_n$ instead of $(f,g)^n$, so as not to confuse the reader into thinking this is the $n$-th power of the first transvectant (the Jacobian).
